# fbs run result in No module named src

Tags: python, pyqt, fbs

I am trying to build executable file with fbs according this web page (https://build-system.fman.io/manual/). Hierarchy of my structure looks like this hierarchy:

[image: Hierarchy]

When I try to fbs run command I get error statement

```
File "D:\Qt\src\main\python\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    from src.main.python.packages import Utilities
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

If I try to import library with

```
from packages import Settings
```

i.e. it is red underlined but I can build it, although with log file I know code won't go to this module. Do you have any suggestion?
I am using Python 3.7

Comment: You don't have to run main.py directly but open a console in `D:\Qt`  and then run in `fbs run`.

Comment: Yes that is what i am doing

Comment: Try implementing the python directory as a source root (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html#mark), this should get rid of the red underlining. Have you looked at the output of fbs freeze via --debug (https://build-system.fman.io/manual/#dependencies) for potential errors? Python 3.7 is not yet officially supported by fbs. It may or may not work, if everything else fails try Python 3.6.